# How to get birthday using Google Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm trying to get the birthday using Google Oauth2
but not sure if I'm doing it right...

Here is the code I'm using:

```
        var googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions();
        googleAuthOptions.ClientId = googleId;
        googleAuthOptions.ClientSecret = googleSecret;

        googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
        googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");

        googleAuthOptions.Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("GoogleAccessToken", context.AccessToken));

                var expiryDuration = context.ExpiresIn ?? new TimeSpan();
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:expires_in", DateTime.UtcNow.Add(expiryDuration).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

                if (context.Email != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:email", context.Email));
                if (context.Id != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:id", context.Id));
                if (context.GivenName != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:given_name", context.GivenName));
                if (context.FamilyName != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:family_name", context.FamilyName));
                if (context.Name != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:name", context.Name));
                if (context.Profile != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:profile", context.Profile));

                if (context.User.GetValue("birthday") != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:birthday", context.User.GetValue("birthday").ToString()));
                if (context.User.GetValue("locale") != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:locale", context.User.GetValue("locale").ToString()));
                if (context.User.GetValue("gender") != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:gender", context.User.GetValue("gender").ToString()));
                if (context.User.GetValue("picture") != null) context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("google:picture", context.User.GetValue("picture").ToString()));

                // Add all other available claims
                foreach (var claim in context.User)
                {
                    var claimType = string.Format("google:{0}", claim.Key);
                    var claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                    if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Google"));
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthOptions);
```

I would love to see a sample of code that works for sure to get the birthday

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED, so other than setting the right scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login)

Make sure that your Google Plus test account profile allow "show birthday year" and also that the birthday is available to the "public"

if that's not enough, google also sends the birthday in yyyy/mm/dd format...
So I'm using this to display MM/dd/yyyy

```html
DateTime dateDateOfBirth;
DateTime.TryParse(vm.DateOfBirth, out dateDateOfBirth);
if (DateAndTime.IsDateValid(vm.DateOfBirth))
{
// By default Google returns yyyy/mm/dd
vm.DateOfBirth = dateDateOfBirth.ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy");
}
else vm.DateOfBirth = string.Empty;
```

[image]