# Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.DateTime google oauth

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth

I am trying to extract the user's Birthdate in Google and persist it to my database but the problem is I am having an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.DateTime", how can I solve this problem?

```
    var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            FirstName = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value,
            LastName = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value,
            Birthdate = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth).Value,
            Country = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Country).Value,
            Email = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value,
            UserName = info.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value
        };
```

Comment: Having some data would help to know what's going on, but you can probably fix it by just converting the string value from the `Principal` to a `DateTime`. Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get birthday using Google Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914274/how-to-get-birthday-using-google-oauth2)